# js and css do not work properly with ini_set

Tags: php, include-path

I used

```
  ini_set('include_path', '../');
```

to change include path and then I included

```
include '../header.php' ;
```

The problem is css files and js files do not work properly due to an error in directory!

How can I include files from other directories and keep css directories working good ?!

Comment: you want `include 'header.php'`

Comment: 'header.php'  contains links for css files . When I included it in a file lies in a different folder Css files do not work

Comment: the `include_path` directive is not related to urls

Comment: thanks , I tried this and it works now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432913/how-to-use-relative-paths-for-included-files-such-as-css

Comment: ok. good to hear that you've managed it

Comment: BTW I'm sorry for mistakes , I'm using stackoverflow for the first time

Answer (score 0):

We can get over that by defining a URL constant that points to the root URL, and use the variable where ever we want.

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/my-app');
```

and include CSS files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/css/style.css">
```